# Java repaint() method issue. Repainting JPanel will disappear painted components in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I created a separate class for JFrame and JPanel, then draw (fillOval in a JFrame class) and draw (fillOval in a JPanel class), and a button that will just animate the JPanel components. But the problem is, whenever i repaint the JPanel class; ---- The JFrame components disappeared. I don't understand why is this happening. I want the JFrame component be permanent for every animation done in JPanel class.

Sample Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TryRepaintIssue extends JFrame
{
    public TryRepaintIssue(){
       thePanel panel = new thePanel();
       add(panel);
       setSize(1000,1000);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.fillOval(100,500,100,100);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TryRepaintIssue();
    }

    public static class thePanel extends JPanel{
        private int y = 100, vector = 1;
        public thePanel(){
            JButton button = new JButton("Play");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                    y += vector;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            add(button);
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(Color.red);
            g2.fillOval(100,y,100,100);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The JFrame components disappeared.

The components do not disappear. The button and panel are still displayed.

I assume you mean the custom painting of the black circle disappears.

> I don't understand why is this happening

The paint() method of the frame is responsible for painting all the child components of the frame. So it repaints the JPanel you add to the frame, which in turn paints the JButton you add to the panel.

It then paints the black circle on top of the panel.

When you click the button you repaint only the "panel" which causes the JButton and the red circle to be painted.

You lose the painting of the black circle because you no longer invoke the code to paint that circle.

If you want the black circle to remain you have a couple of options:

1. The best solution is to NOT override paint() on the frame. Instead do all the custom painting in your panel. So paint both the black and red circles.
2. repaint the entire frame in your ActionListener code:

   ```
   //repaint();
   SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(button).repaint();
   ```
3. use the Glass Pane as suggested in the answer by Tom.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't override `JFrame.paint`, particularly without calling the `super`. Usually drawing in these situations is done on a [glass pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).

Comment: Note that you may also override the paintComponent / paint method of the content pane, just never override any paint stuff of your JFrame.
(I personally think that GlassPane might be a bit too much for just simple drawing.)